# jQuery Button Toggle Same Button In Different Areas of the page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Greetings Stack Overflow!

I'm struggling with resolving a jQuery button toggle issue.

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7's collapse feature to display multiple(around 12) expandable sections on a page. The collapse features work great. My problem is when it comes to clicking the button, which I'd like to handle using jQuery. The button is supposed to toggle between two lines of text('Expand Story' and 'Collapse Story') along with a font-awesome angle-up carrot that switches between up and down when the section is expanded or collapsed.

With my first attempt, I'm sure there is a better way, but it is what I could come up with in my inexperienced head - each time I click the 'Expand Story' button, all of the 'Expand Story' buttons change.

For some reason, I can't wrap my head around making each button that is clicked, unique. I had thought maybe I could use  `.attr('aria-controls');`  somehow to target the specific button instance because those are unique to each button on the page.

In the end, I only need the button clicked to have its text and up/down carrot change.

I know the JS Fiddle isn't working exactly like I had it, hopefully its close enough to convey what I was trying to do. Please help me come up with a better jQuery solution. I appreciate your suggestions! Thank you!

I have a mostly-working

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ksuo7bpL/1/)

to hopefully help illustrate what I'm trying to do and what problem I'm having.

Comment: Hello @GordenSmith. I believe I understood from your _jsfiddle_ what you were trying to do. Take a look at the demo below and see if it accomplishes what you want. If not, I'm happy to expand on it some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the example below gets you on the right track:

**DEMO:**

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('a.collapse-trigger').on('click', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    
    if($($this.attr('href')).is(":visible")) {
      $($this.attr('href')).slideUp();
      $this.find('.col-txt')
        .hide()
        .siblings('.exp-txt')
        .show();
    } else {
      $($this.attr('href')).slideDown();
      $this.find('.exp-txt')
        .hide()
        .siblings('.col-txt')
        .show();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.col-txt {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- First Title -->
<div class="container-wrapper container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 story-content">
        <h1 class="mb-2 mt-5">Our Team</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- First Story -->
<div class="collapse" id="c11">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <!-- Nav tabs -->
     <ul class="nav nav-tabs red text-center" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active float-none d-inline-block"><a href="#CFT_Staff" aria-controls="CFT_Staff" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">CFT Staff</a></li>
     <li role="presentation" class=" float-none d-inline-block"><a href="#Trustees" aria-controls="gifts" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Trustees</a></li>
     <li role="presentation" class=" float-none d-inline-block"><a href="#Advisory_Council" aria-controls="Advisory_Council" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Advisory Council</a></li>
     </ul>
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content sort-by-team">
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="CFT_Staff">
       <div class="row mb-5">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
         <span class="fs-16 text-uppercase fw-600 d-inline-block pb-4 mt-5">Sort by team:</span>
        <a class="d-block mb-2 fs-16 fw-600 active" href="#">Leadership</a>
        <a class="d-block mb-2 fs-16 fw-600" href="#">Donor Services & Relationships</a>
        <a class="d-block mb-2 fs-16 fw-600" href="#">Finance & Administration</a>
        <a class="d-block mb-2 fs-16 fw-600" href="#">Philanthropy & Grants</a>
        <a class="d-block mb-2 fs-16 fw-600" href="#">Educate Texas</a>
        <a class="d-block mb-2 fs-16 fw-600" href="#">Communications</a>
        <a class="d-block mb-2 fs-16 fw-600" href="#">Nort Texas Giving Day & Gift Processing</a>
                <a class="d-block mb-2 fs-16 fw-600" href="#">View All Staff</a>
        </div>
       <div class="col-sm-9 staff-list">
         <div class="row mt-5">
         <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img class="img-responsive mx-auto mb-2" src="../annual-report/images/staff_DaveScullin.jpg">
          <span class="fs-18 d-block mb-1 text-center fw-600">David J. Scullin</span>
          <span class="fs-14 d-block text-center pos-title">President & CEO</span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img class="img-responsive mx-auto mb-2" src="../annual-report/images/staff_BethBull.jpg">
          <span class="fs-18 d-block mb-1 text-center fw-600">Elizabeth W. Bull</span>
          <span class="fs-14 d-block text-center pos-title">Senior Vice President and Chief Financial Officer</span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img class="img-responsive mx-auto mb-2" src="../annual-report/images/staff_JohnFitzpatrick.jpg">
          <span class="fs-18 d-block mb-1 text-center fw-600">John Fitzpatrick</span>
          <span class="fs-14 d-block text-center pos-title">Executive Director, Educate Texas</span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img class="img-responsive mx-auto mb-2" src="../annual-report/images/staff_SarahSnelson.jpg">
          <span class="fs-18 d-block mb-1 text-center fw-600">Sarah Cotton Nelson</span>
          <span class="fs-14 d-block text-center pos-title">Chief Philanthropy Officer</span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img class="img-responsive mx-auto mb-2" src="../annual-report/images/staff_MonicaEgertSmith.jpg">
          <span class="fs-18 d-block mb-1 text-center fw-600">Monica Egert Smith</span>
          <span class="fs-14 d-block text-center pos-title">Chief Relationships Officer</span>
                  </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img class="img-responsive mx-auto mb-2" src="../annual-report/images/staff_SusanSwan-Smith.jpg">
          <span class="fs-18 d-block mb-1 text-center fw-600">Susan Swan Smith</span>
          <span class="fs-14 d-block text-center pos-title">Chief Giving Day Officer</span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
          <img class="img-responsive mx-auto mb-2" src="../annual-report/images/gtang.jpg">
          <span class="fs-18 d-block mb-1 text-center fw-600">George Tang</span>
          <span class="fs-14 d-block text-center pos-title">Managing Director, Educate Texas</span>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
     <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Trustees">...</div>
       <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="Advisory_Council">...</div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- First Story Expand -->
<div class="border-bottom-med-gray">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <a class="dark-gray-text pt-3 pb-6 d-inline-block fs-14 text-uppercase btn-expand-story collapse-trigger" href="#c11" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="c11">
          <span class="exp-txt">Expand</span>
          <span class="col-txt">Collapse</span>
          Story
          <i class="pl-1 fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="pl-1 fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<!-- Second Title -->
<div class="container-wrapper container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 story-content">
        <h1 class="mb-2 mt-5">Introducing the New CFTexas.org</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Second Story -->
<div class="collapse" id="c12">
      <div class="container">
    <div class="row pt-4">
     <div class="col-sm-6">
      <p>Our website has been completely redesigned with you in mind, to make giving easier, more effective and more enjoyable than ever before. Get inspired by browsing our library of impact stories, stay up-to-date on our community impact initiatives, meet our esteemed CFT experts and trustees, view upcoming events and more. Take a look around an... [missing full info]</p>
            <a href="https://www.cftexas.org/" class="btn btn-text text-left mw-200 mb-0 d-block mt-5 fs-16" role="button"><span><span class="text-uppercase">Visit our new site</span></a>
     </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6">
      <img class="img-responsive mx-auto" src="../annual-report/images/laptop.jpg">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>

<!-- Second Story Expand -->
<!-- First Story Expand -->
<div class="border-bottom-med-gray">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <a class="dark-gray-text pt-3 pb-6 d-inline-block fs-14 text-uppercase btn-expand-story collapse-trigger" href="#c12" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="c11">
          <span class="exp-txt">Expand</span>
          <span class="col-txt">Collapse</span>
          Story
          <i class="pl-1 fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i><i class="pl-1 fa fa-angle-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

You on the right track but need a few modifications. Rather than targeting all elements with a particular class name, you can use some jQuery selectors like `.find()` and `.siblings()` to find only the elements that are related to the same story button as the one that is clicked. This allows you to alter the text and expand the stories one by one, rather than having a handler that affects all stories at once.

As a note, I removed the `data-toggle="collapse"` attribute from the links and added a class of `collapse-trigger`. The default *Bootstrap 3* functionality was interferring with the customer `click` event. In order to do the custom handler, I needed to stop the default functionality from occuring.

Comment: Yes, this did get me on the right track to a solution! Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1) target the specific collapsable button by class.just create one...lets say ".chevron-toggle" 
2) make the jquery script find the carret of that specific button with that specific class using .this
3) toggle the class inside that jquery.

```
/*------------- css ------------*/
.rotate-chevron{
    -moz-transition: all .3s linear;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s linear;
    transition: all .3s linear;
}

.rotate-chevron.down{
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

/*------------- html ------------*/


<div  class="chevron-toggle accordion-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#Accordion" data-target="#content_inside" aria-expanded="false">
     <h4>
       Edit Info 
       <i class="rotate-chevron fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
     </h4>
</div>

<div id="content_inside" class=" collapse" aria-expanded="false">
hello
</div>


//JQuery Chevron rotation
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.chevron-toggle').click(function(e) {
      $(this).find(".rotate-chevron").toggleClass("down");  
  });

});
```